# When is a class too big?

Tags: oop

I tend to create very large classes that have 30-40 (or more) methods.  How many methods are too many?  Are there any "smells" or rules of thumb to use?

Comment: Hard to tell without a sample.

Comment: My instinct would be that it doesn't matter as long as they make sense.

Comment: Short answer: If it makes sense to split it into two or more, you should.

Answer (score 51):

Step one is to adhere to the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). If you can't say in one sentence what your class does, then it probably does too much.

Once you've narrowed that down, I don't know that the number of methods really matters as long as your methods [don't do too much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129599/best-rule-for-maximum-function-size/129647).

Comment: Using one sentence is a pretty good heuristic.  Thanks for the links.

Comment: Agreed +1. But rather than the 'one sentence' rule, I prefer Uncle Bob's definition of SRP: a class should have one and only one reason to change.

Comment: That sentence also shouldn't use the words "AND" or "OR"

Comment: I have a base controller class 2000+ lines long. Maybe it does too much but I need all those methods for children classes. Should I use traits to split the class? "Single Responsibility Principle" is a good concept but often it sucks

Comment: I have a base character (unit) comtroller for an RTT game, which exceeds 2500 rows of code - I find it hard to manage, deapite I split up things in to several components - I am not sure how to deal with it - may I have any suggestions ?

Comment: Second link is no longer available, question was deleted.

Answer (score 29):

I'll bite. Without doing much more than wading into the very shallow edges of the deep waters of O-O design, I'll through a couple of my rules of thumb:

1. Static properties are highly questionable. Question yourself strongly about whether or not they are really needed.
2. Most properties/attributes of a class should be private (accessable only by the object instance) or protected, accessable only by an instance of the class or of a derived class (subclass).
3. If a property/attribute of a class is visible to the general public, it should most likely  be read-only. For the most part, the state of an object instance should change only by its responding to a method asking it to do something useful (e.g., you request that a window move itself, rather than explicitly setting is origin on the coordinate plane).
4. Public Getter/Setter methods or properties are questionable as they primarily expose object state (which see item #2 above).
5. Public methods should primarily expose the logical operations (messages) to which an object instance responds. These operations should be atomic (e.g., for the object to be in a logically consistent internal state, it should not depend on an external actors sending it a particular sequence of messages). Object state should change are as result of responding to these messages and should be exposed as a **side effect** of the message (e.g., a window reporting its location as a side effect of asking it to move is acceptable).

The above should cut down the public interface to your objects considerably.

Finally, if your object has more than a few messages to which it responds, you likely have a candidate for refactoring: is it really one monolithic object, or is it an assembly of discrete objects? "More than a few", of course, is a highly subjective (and contextual) number -- I'll throw out 10-12 as a reasonable limit.

Hope this helps.

There are lots of books out there on O-O design, analysis and modelling.

Comment: nice list - my more than a few number is 7.

Comment: @Nicholas Carey how do you pass data into object, without getters and setters? You still have to fill this object somehow, and public properties are 'forbidden'.. ?

Comment: @Andrew. You use the constructor(s), factories or factory methods, or dependency injection and you pass data via *methods* when you ask the object instance to perform a task in its domain. Change of state isn't made explicitly: it occurs naturally as a *side effect* of the object performing work within its domain.

Comment: @NicholasCarey but what about saving object data to persistance (e.g. database) and fetching from it? The DB Mapper class must have some kind of access to object's properties in order to 'fill them' or 'read from them'. Object should not know who saves it and where.

Comment: @NicholasCarey I'd argue that dependency injection frameworks sometimes (often?) rely on setters.

Answer (score 9):

As others have said, a class is too big when it is trying to do more than one thing and [violates the Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

An excellent book on this and other topics (and one I strongly recommend for any developer) is [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) by Bob Martin.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a good link to Bob Martin's stuff. He's a bit of a zealot in terms of methods containing only one control-flow structure, but that gets you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

static classes such as Math are likely to have lots of methods. It would be confusing to split them.

Comment: +1 Good Point and a great example of a large class. (Though it could be a facade for a well-organized set of other classes too.)

Answer (score 4):

A general guideline for design: if a reasonable person's first reaction to a <set of things> could plausibly be "That's too many <thing>s!", then it's too many <thing>s.

Comment: I was on a sailing trip on a schooner once. It was pretty brisk day and great sailing. I was taking a turn at the wheel and asked the skipper how he determined when it was time to tuck in a reef (shorten sail). His response? "The first time someboday asks whether it might be time to reef. ALL HANDS ON DECK TO SHORTEN SAIL!"

Answer (score 3):

Number of methods by itself is not a reliable indicator.  What if 20 of those are just property getters?

Try metrics that are more concrete, though this is always a judgment call.  There is a list of 'code smells' [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html).

Comment: *What if 20 of those are just property getters*...Then you are exposing too many properties :-P.

Comment: @Mark Peters Yes, it's important to make sure you adhere to the Arbitrarily-Small Number of Properties principle - it's the last of the DOGMA principles of OOP. ;P

Comment: Haha :-).  I don't adhere strictly to any single POV, but I found this old article on the subject worth a read: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html?page=1.

Answer (score 3):

It's all relative but check out the [single responsibility principle:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

> In object-oriented programming, the
>   single responsibility principle states
>   that every object should have a single
>   responsibility, and that
>   responsibility should be entirely
>   encapsulated by the class

A rule of thumb i've thought of for SRP: Count your usings/imports/includes. If your class has more than half a dozen there's a good chance that you're violating the SRP. But that's a relative idea as well. Certain patterns such as facades will violate this rule out of necessity. E.g. as in simplifying and hiding a complex subsytem.

Comment: Counting imports is interesting.  Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2):

A point about it is taken in the "Effective C++" 3rd edition:
"Prefer non-member, non-friend functions to member functions". What this means that you should keep your class reasonable small because big classes tend to be difficult to expand (the do not scale well)

You could also check you class for branches. If your class contains may "if's" or "switch'es" there is a high chance that your class responsibility has dissolved. If this is the case refactoring and cutting the responsibilities into smaller parts may lead to smaller classes.

Best Regards,
Marcin

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not you can split the class in to subclasses.

Edit: What I mean is that you should ask yourself "does this method apply to this class or would it belong to a subclass?"

For example,

```
Class Animal
  - dog_bark()
```

dog_bark() could be moved to a class named Dog, and the method renamed to bark()

Comment: Yes you can split it into subclasses.  You don't have any external requirements.

Comment: Edited response. Clarified what I meant.  I did not mean to imply that there were requirements for splitting a class up.

Comment: I understand your example.  My question is about big classes or subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.
If you are in Java with get/set pairs for each field, I'm not surprised.  But if each of those methods are 100+ line beasts, that would be a smell.

Comment: I do use Java but I'm not talking about Javabeans or setters/getters in general.

Answer (score 0):

There is never a thing as too large of a class, when the PHP interpreter reads your code it compiles into one large executable black of code so splitting them up makes little difference on performance.

BUT:

When it comes down to programming you should never really need 40+ methods in one class, and should be split up into there entites.

Example

```
class HTTP
{
    /*
        * Base functions for HTTP Fetching / transferring / Sending
        * so when it comes to single responsibility this would be the the fetch / set in HTTP
    */
}
```

then you would be more specific with your subclasses such as

```
class YoutubeUploader extends HTTP
{
    /*
        * This class is responsible for uploading to youtube only
     */
}

class YoutubeDownload extends HTTP
{
    /*
        * This class is responsible for downloading to youtube only
     */
}

class CronRunner extends HTTP
{
    /*
        * This class is responsible for Running your HTTP Cron Tasks
     */
}
```

no if you did not have that BASE HTTP Class you would have to define methods in all three sub classes to transfer data via the HTTP Protocol.

Splitting your classes up unto single responsibilities gives a more structured framework resulting in less code and more outcome.

Everyone ahs already mentioned the: [Single Responsibility Principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)  but its something you should really understand.

There's also ways to reduce code in classes, take this example

```
class User
{
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $data['username']; 
    }

    public function getPermissions()
    {
        return $data['permissions'];
    }

    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $data['firstname']; 
    }
}
```

this are not really needed when you can do:

```
class User
{
    public function __call($method,$params = array())
    {
        if(substr(0,3,$method) == "get")
        {
            $var_name = substr(3,strlen($method),$method);
            return $data[$var_name];
        }
    }
}
```

This would take car of any method called that starts with 'get' and it takes the last portion of the string and searches the array.

Comment: Hmm...really?  You'd sacrifice static method call checking to cut down on a few accessor methods?  Maybe I don't know much about whatever language you're using there.

Comment: you have confused me, who said anything about static method call checking ?

Comment: yes, I agree with you, but in regards to the question at hand, its specifically asked *When is a class too big*, now what I tried to accomplish with my answer is to describe the methods of cutting down lines of code to keep a class less then a specific length, in regards to bugs etc, well to be honest in such a loosely typed language like php the only real way to avoid bugs in code is to implement exceptions, error tracking etc. sometimes dynamic methods work, in a language like `C#` I would never even think about creating such a method.

Comment: Eh nm, you say it's PHP.  I would be really hesitant about this anyway.  The problem with big classes isn't their performance, it's their maintainability and flexibility, etc.  Your last suggestion exposes ALL properties, basically throwing aside any ideal of encapsulation.  I'd be really careful with it, even when used in a language that's not compiled.

Comment: yes, but as its seeking an array the array would only expose public properties, unlike `$this->{$var_name}`, you obviously have greater knowledge with application architecture than I do, so I take your words in wisely, I still think its reasonable attempt.

Comment: A quibble: I disagree with extending HTTP here. You should prefer encapsulation to inheritance, particularly where there's no necessary connection between the base class and its children. What if you need to use a different protocol or API to upload? IMO it would be better for the uploader classes to own and use a reference to a protocol class that hides HTTP/FTP/API differences from the uploader, instead of extending (and thereby forever coupling to) HTTP.

Comment: `API` is not a protocol but an interface that uses protocols to transfer data. when it comes to web development 99% of API's uses the HTTP Protocol. and FTP is pretty redundant for web uploading services.

Answer (score 0):

In general a class should be designed to do one thing and to do it well. Now, with your example of the Math class, it can act as a facade to seperate implementations. Or it can be split up into hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Math 
{

       abstract Solve(IMathPayload);
       abstract CanSolve(IMathPayload);
}

public class LinearMath : Math {}

public class DifferentialEquasionMath: Math {}
```

Answer (score 0):

One strategy I like to follow is to create a 'Handle' class for each data model object. Because the handle is responsible for only modification of
that data object, it follows SRP. If I need to create classes outside of data object modification, at least I know most of the code already is SRP compliant.